# rails deployment failing - bitbucket and capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ubuntu, bitbucket

I am trying to deploy rails application to ec2 server from bitbucket repository.
When I run bundle exec cap staging deploy, I get the following error. Looking for help with how to solve this...I have followed the instructions on SSH key setup etc but that is not helping.

```
DEBUG [a02447fc]    Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG [a02447fc]    
DEBUG [a02447fc]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [a02447fc]    
DEBUG [a02447fc]    
DEBUG [a02447fc]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [a02447fc]    
DEBUG [a02447fc]    and the repository exists.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ubuntu@**IP address**: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
git stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
git stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => git:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as ubuntu@**IP addess**: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
git stderr: Nothing written

** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:

bundler: failed to load command: cap (/home/admin1/mysite/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/cap)
```

Comment: Are you using the same user for the deploy script that you setup the SSH key for?

Comment: thank you so much i got it....